# Magento order invoicing error

Tags: orders

We have Magento instance with order edit extension.
And payment solution is strip.
When I'm want to add 1 more item using order edit extension I'm getting following error:

> An error occured while saving the order You cannot use a Stripe token
>   more than once: tok_18RJXYKTR3xpmuE2c8unIjCS.

How to debug the above issue, I mean its related to order edit extension or strip payment method issue?

Comment: Apologies for the close here but the number of factors to debug this make it difficult for us to answer here on Magento.SE. Perhaps you can ask your question on community.magento.com instead? 

At any rate, editing orders is bad accounting practice. Read through this: http://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/doing-things-the-magento-way

Comment: @philwinkle agreed.

Answer (score 1):

This just shows one reason, why an "order edit" extension is a bad idea.

Magento does not offer this feature for good reasons. Orders are required to not change as soon as they exist in the system and have an order number. Without such an extension, if you edit an order in the backend, the order actually gets canceled and a new one is created.

This way you are not breaking any local laws and also don't get in trouble with payment providers and other extensions which assume that orders do not change.

IMHO  the only reasonable solution is to delete this order edit extension.